# allow multiple languages on pdf puppeteer nodejs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser

I am using puppeteer for generating pdf from server side , we are passing Angular application web url on server api which will return pdf .
Everything is running cool , but we having two languages on pdf . It will supporting English ('en') but we the text from Marathi ('mr') language was shown rendering .

```
  pdfDownloadWithPuppeteer: async (req, res, err) => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
            {
                headless: true,
                executablePath: '/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-674921/chrome-linux/chrome',
                args: \['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'\]

            });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        // added below code for setting up language headers
        await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
            'Accept-Language': 'mr'
        });
        await page.goto( myWebUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }), { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0 });
            const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4', printBackground: true });
            await browser.close();
            fs.writeFile('myProfile.pdf', pdf, function (err) {
                debugger
                if (err) {
                    console.log("server error");
                }
                res.download('myProfile.pdf')
            })
```

- added screenshot (rendering only English language)

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919398/6161265

Comment: Thanks @Md.AbuTaher , i checked this link , installed required font but its not working , I also tried by adding ttf files inside usr/shared/fonts folder on server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding fonts to Puppeteer PDF renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033223/adding-fonts-to-puppeteer-pdf-renderer)

Comment: I wasn't sure but now I know it's same issue as the one I linked. You just have to use the correct command to install correct fonts and clear your cache properly.

Comment: tried with same not good luck for me @Md.AbuTaher

Comment: Give me a link to the actual url.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the font is not there in the system where your server is running, So install the desired font in your server system.
For Ubuntu system, you can refer this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fonts

Answer (score 0):

I installed the arabic fonts for ubuntu
then it works

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install -y fonts-kacst-one